# .Net Application - Microsoft Text driver issue

Tags: .net, text, driver

I am using Microsoft text driver to read data from a CSV file in my .net application.
The problem is, it is running fine in my local machine, but when i run in my server i am getting the following error.

'[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified'

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your development environment 32-bit and your server 64-bit?

Comment: yes, my machine is 32-bit and my server is 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that your development workstation is 32-bit and your server is 64-bit. As far as I know, there is no 64-bit Text Driver.

Your best option is to change your application from `Any CPU` to `x86` so that it always runs 32-bit.